# References on the relations between Top, Diff and PL

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, geometric-topology

I have heard many times informal statements like "differentiable and pl manifolds are essentially the same for such and such dimensions", but I would like to know what they mean exactly and how such statements are proved. However, I have been unable to find a reference about such topics.

Do you know of any books or review papers that treat this kind of issues in detail?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/97019/33248) for a related question on MO has tons of information. It should be a good start.