# In what dimensions are PL and Diff equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have read in different places, that for $n\leq 4$, PL and Diff are equivalent (passing through PDIFF). I believe Milnor gave an example of the inequivalence for $n=7$. What about for $n=5$ or $n=6$? Are there examples of PL manifolds which are not smoothable?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96670/classification-of-surfaces-and-the-top-diff-and-pl-categories-for-manifolds.

Answer (score 3):

A more qeneral question is [References on the relations between Top, Diff and PL](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891285). It gives a reference to https://mathoverflow.net/q/96670 which gives a complete (positive) answer for $n =5, 6$.